# Obtaining distance and orientation derivatives in pydrake

Tags: drake

We are designing a controller in pydrake which requires the following information:

1. Closest point pairs and minimum distance between the robot and objects, along with derivatives of these values with respect to the robot's state q (i.e. the Jacobian from the closest point pairs to q). We noticed the `CalcDistanceDerivatives` function but it is internal.
2. Derivative of the orientation of the end effector with respect to q. We know there is an `OrientationConstraint` but the needed information does not seem to be directly available without adding the constraint.
3. Other information we may want to obtain, but pydrake or C++ does not provide the corresponding exposed API.

What is the best workflow if we have to modify the Drake source code? Should we implement all of our algorithms in C++, or add Python bindings to the modified C++ code and still use Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Closest point pairs and minimum distance between the robot and objects, along with derivatives of these values with respect to the robot's state q (i.e. the Jacobian from the closest point pairs to q). We noticed the CalcDistanceDerivatives function but it is internal.

There are two ways to obtain this information. One is using [CollisionChecker](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/7dd9c1a89e4f4ffac9bad78481147c37f709eb4e/planning/collision_checker.h#L185) class. The second is to use ComputeSignedDistancePairwiseClosestDistance (you can find an example [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/7dd9c1a89e4f4ffac9bad78481147c37f709eb4e/multibody/inverse_kinematics/minimum_distance_constraint.cc#L40-L45))

> Derivative of the orientation of the end effector with respect to q. We know there is an OrientationConstraint but the needed information does not seem to be directly available without adding the constraint.

To get this Jacobian matrix, you can call MultibodyPlant::CalcJacobianAngularVelocity [function](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/7dd9c1a89e4f4ffac9bad78481147c37f709eb4e/multibody/plant/multibody_plant.h#L4007).

> Other information we may want to obtain, but pydrake or C++ does not provide the corresponding exposed API.

Could you give the example? The function are probably available inside MultibodyPlant or SceneGraph classes.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! For the first part, I don't see a Python API for `ComputeSignedDistancePairwiseClosestDistance`. Does this mean it would be better for me to switch to C++ instead of pydrake? Also, if I can get the closest point on the robot, I suppose I could use it with the Jacobian to compute the derivative of distance with respect to q. Is this a proper workflow, or is the derivative already available somewhere?

Comment: The Python API is in https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.geometry.html?highlight=computesigneddistance#pydrake.geometry.QueryObject.ComputeSignedDistancePairClosestPoints.

Comment: The derivative of the distance w.r.t q is computed in https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/fc6d4e217fc7adc7a4d49344bc75da8d095e7be0/multibody/inverse_kinematics/distance_constraint_utilities.cc#L8-L42

Comment: I don't see any API documentation for the `CalcDistanceDerivatives` function in either the C++ or Python libraries. It seems this function is not exposed to the public APIs.

Comment: CalcDistanceDerivatives is not exposed to the public API. But it is just a few lines, I think you can just copy that function into your code?